# I am looking for mutual exclusivity examples in law

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law

This is where, A is legal, B is legal, but they're not both legal, at the same time.

Can there be examples in criminal law, across jurisdictions?

I can only think of 2 examples in civil law, but only applying to restaurant type things. Here in Chicago in 1993 they went after a strip club, saying you guys are welcome to serve alcohol, you guys are welcome to have topless performers, but can't have both at the same time.

And I'm sure it's common that restaurants that serve children (and other things) cannot do that and allow for smoking at the same time. Would like to find some non-restaurant examples in civil law. Thanks.

Comment: That is literally every law ever. I challenge you to find one where your description *doesn't* fit.

Comment: @nvoigt robbery and rape are 2 different crimes...

Comment: They are. But I have no idea what that has to do with your question. You are looking for instances, where a legal A and a legal B at the same time are illegal. That is *everything* illegal. (unless the pure existance of something is outlawed in your juristiction). Robbery? Is showing a knife and asking for money. Both legal, unless combined. Rape? Not listening to your girlfriend and having sex with her. Both legal, unless combined. Every single law is about doing *something* while *something*. Drinking is legal, driving is legal, combined it's a DUI.

Comment: @nvoigt for example owning a car is legal, owning a piano is legal, and owning both is legal. Watering garden legal, playing the piano legal, doing both together still legal. So yes, DUI is another example, and I don't think there are many examples, aside from being a ____ and doing X at the same time, as opposed to doing X and Y. So, being a felon, and owning a pitbull dog, being a felon and owning a gun, etc.

Comment: Oh yea, I heard in Germany if you have a raccoon as a pet, you have to own 2 raccoons so they entertain each other, owning only 1 is illegal, or some jurisdiction.

Comment: @NealConroy This is an unconstrained list uestion. There are **way** too many things that are this.

Comment: @Trish I apologize, you can delete this q.

Answer (score 7):

Examples where each of the things is legal on its own, but not when they both occur:

- (1) voting in favour of a development permit as member of a local government (e.g. city councillor); (2) having a pecuniary interest in the lot at issue
- (1) doing anything that is otherwise legal; (2) having the purpose of carrying out an intention to commit an offence — (1) and (2) together make out an attempted crime in Canada
- (1) entering a contract to provide a service S; (2) not providing service S — although it may be a stretch to call a breach of contract *illegal*
- (1) being married to A; (2) being married to B
- for a long time (and is still true in many places): (1) being a man; (2) marrying a man
- in places in the U.S. prior to *Loving v. Virginia*, 388 U.S. 1 (1967): (1) being a Black person; (2) marrying a white person
- (1) being mildly but definitely intoxicated; (2) operating a vehicle
- (1) using a cell phone held in one's hand; (2) driving a vehicle
- and many more; that's just the tip of the iceberg.